# Can Cure Light Wounds Mass target the same creature more than once on its casting?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, healing, targeting

When you cast the mass version of the [cure light wounds](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cure-light-wounds#mass) spell, its range changes from touch to close and from creature touched to creature touched/level with targets within 30 feet of each other. To this sounds like a ray spell as you would have to make an attack roll vs every creature (this is because you could target undead and living creatures with the same casting). Is it possible to have the same creature targeted by the spell more than once? I dont see any place which states you can only affect a creature once with the casting.

**Update:**

Since there has been debate over how the rules should be applied in this case, lets do a comparison with out multiple touch spells.

- [Cure Wounds](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cure-light-wounds/) mass spells "Target one creature/level, no two of which can be more than 30 ft. apart"
- [Chill Touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chill-touch) "Targets creature or creatures touched (up to one/level)"
- [Haste](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/) "Targets one creature/level, no two of which can be more than 30 ft. apart"
- [Bull's Strength mass](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bull-s-strength/) "Targets one creature/level, no two of which can be more than 30 ft. apart"
- [Cat's Grace mass](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cat-s-grace) - "Targets one creature/level, no two of which can be more than 30 ft. apart"

Since I dont know of anyone who can successfully claim that Chill Touch cant be applied to the same target multiple times in a round assuming a sufficient bab or hasted. Someone can be affected by multiple haste spells, but only one has the effect, and is not helpful doubling up in this case because its part of the same spell so any effect that would dispel or counter one would get all instances of it. Same with Bulls and Cats. The most important difference is that the others except for Chill Touch say "One creature" but that can be thought of in two ways. The one likely intended being that a creature can only be selected once for the spell, or the creature can be selected multiple times each time taking up one of the creature targets.

Comment: This is actually a tough rules question to find arguments against.

Comment: It has just enough possibility and vagueness that I thought it could be possible. It would sure make the mass versions of the cure (and inflict) spells so much more useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Targeting the same creature multiple times simultaneously with the same effect causes the creature to be affected still only once

That is, this GM would rule that just because an effect can be used *one* time against *multiple* targets doesn't mean that the same effect can instead apply *multiple* times against *one* target and yield *multiple* results.

While it can be *technically* lawyered that a spell that affects multiple creatures can, instead, affect the same creature multiple times, that notion doesn't yield positive results in actual play (i.e. you'll earn a book to the noggin not applause). And, as you can see from broaching the question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/88221/8610), even bringing up the idea is anathema to some.

To put this negative reaction in perspective, let me employ an analogy: a game show contestant is allowed to pick two cars. While most contestants will pick two *different* cars, this contestant baffles host and studio audience by picking the *same* car *twice*, *technically* picking two cars: this car and this car *again*. Although this impresses the game show's lawyers, and the sponsor's pleased at the prospect of only having to provide one vehicle, this makes for lousy ratings. Seriously, don't do this: you don't want to make [Drew Carey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drew_Carey#The_Price_Is_Right)—or the GM—angry.

That said, the spell [*mass cure light wounds*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cure-light-wounds#mass) targets "one creature/level, no two of which can be more than 30 ft. apart." However, once the caster has picked that one creature to be affected, picking that same creature likely runs afoul of of [Combining Magical Effects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Combining-Magic-Effects): the creature is supposed to realize *simultaneously* enough the *same* spell's effect *multiple* times, something the game usually either rejects outright or accommodates grudgingly (by mandating only the most recent, most beneficial, or most detrimental effect occurs).

With that in mind, a GM *could* allow a lone creature to be targeted multiple times by a *mass cure light wounds* spell then have only the highest individual result affect the target… or even have the target affected uniquely only once, the GM mandating all creatures that the spell would've affected would've been affected equally.

Compare the spell *mass cure light wounds* with the spell [*wail of the banshee*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wail-of-the-banshee): the *wail* targets "one living creature/level within a 40-ft.-radius spread," and "[c]reatures closest to the point of origin are affected first." This does *not* mean if a Wiz20 catches but two creatures in that 40-ft.-radius spread, the wizard can force those two creatures to make 10 successful Fortitude saving throws each or die! Each affected creature instead makes 1 saving throw, and the remainder of the spell's effect is wasted. (By the way, here's [a Paizo messageboard discussion](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2q3xh&page=1?Clear-questions-about-Wail-of-the-Banshee) about the spell *wail of the banshee*.)

This GM urges that unless a spell or effect says otherwise, a decision to use the spell or effect against *less* than than its maximum number of targets doesn't make the spell or effect's power *greater* against the targets the spell or effect *is* used against!

(I could find but this lone [2011 Paizo messageboard thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mif6?Targeting-rules-with-spells#1) discussing the idea of picking the same target multiple times for an effect that affects multiple creatures. The topic doesn't seem to warrant serious consideration.)

Comment: Spell stacking rules apply to “[s]pells that provide **bonuses or penalties** on attack rolls, damage rolls, saving throws, and other attributes”. Healing (like damage) isn't a bonus or a penalty, and anyway isn't in the set of effects that doesn't stack, so isn't this reasoning moot?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The Stacking Effects section of [Combining Magic Effects](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html#combining-magic-effects) applies to more than bonuses and penalties, despite the opening paragraph. Even if my word is insufficient, it's hard to argue that multiple mental control effects are a bonus or penalty. If we assume that part isn't aberrant, then the rest should apply to spells that do things besides generate bonuses or penalties, like spells enabling mental control or even healing.

Comment: I read that the other way around: general rule (“Combining Magical Effecgt”, most spells don't affect each other), more-specific general rule (“Stacking Effects”, spells providing mods don't stack w/ self; same type mods don't stack), specific rule (“Multiple Mental Control Effects”, mental control effects have a special stacking rule). So I don't think an argument can be made that mental control effects having an explicit rule implies an analoguous implicit rule for all other effects, especially given the general rule (spells don't affect each other).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Just to be clear, when you read, "*Same Effect with Differing Results:* The same spell can sometimes produce varying effects if applied to the same recipient more than once. Usually the last spell in the series trumps the others. None of the previous spells are actually removed or dispelled, but their effects become irrelevant while the final spell in the series lasts," you mentally insert after each *spell* a bracketed *that grants a bonus or inflicts a penalty*? And you do that for each *spell* in that section except the mental effects part?

Comment: Yes, because that is explicitly in the scope of the heading “Stacking Effects”, which is about effects that provide bonuses and penalties, and nothing internal to that rule specifies a different scope (like the mental control effects rule does).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Except, obviously, for mental control effects, of course, which get tossed into that section anyway. Man, I wish we weren't discussing *Pathfinder.* The *Player's Handbook* examples—that Paizo couldn't use and that Paizo didn't replace in *Pathfinder* with its own examples—make it clear that the section really isn't supposed to be limited to bonuses and penalties, using *stack* broadly for *combine for cumulative effect* rather than narrowly for *adding bonuses and subtracting penalties*.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean! I haven't read that page in a while. While there though, it's worth noting the paragraph at the top of page 172 covers instantaneous effects, like damage or healing, saying they *are* cumulative, but in a much clearer way than the spare (but matching!) equivalent rule says in PFRPG/PRD. I think, anyway it's sliced, it's safe to say that same healing/damage aren't  prevented by the stacking rules.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I agree! But while the *mass cure light wounds* spell's result would be instantaneous healing, to *get* that result requires resolving first the spell's *targeting* issue that the question raises. That is, this is *not*, like Instantaneous Effects says, "Two or more spells with instantaneous durations work[ing] cumulatively when they affect the same target," but *one* spell trying to affecting the *same* creature multiple times *simultaneously*, something the rules aren't precise about (hence, in my answer, preceding *run afoul* with *likely*).

Comment: Yep, that's why I focused on the targeting issue in my post. If the targeting were (say) a number of rays, then I think it would work to double or triple up, but the line is written in a way that dodges that possibility.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie And while I am totally on board with that common sense approach--and agree that, for instance, multiple rays would heal or deal damage multiple times--, I don't think anywhere in the rules there's  *explicitly* a picked-or-not dichotomy for, for example, spells targeting 1 creature/level. (Truthfully, I think such an odd reading is so rare that it takes the Internet for that reading to happen in the first place.) That's why I went with the *closest* rules *and* analogized why folks would think a dude daft if he tried violating that dichotomy in actual play.

Comment: I think the target line itself explicitly says there is such a dichotomy. Unless we're going to posit that counting operates differently in PFRPG than normal. Under normal English expressions of counting operations, “one creature/level” can't be read to give permission to count one creature as two creatures.

Comment: And I, on the *just barely* other hand, think the target line instead only *strongly implies* such a dichotomy. The pick-the-same-thing-multiple-times is a common enough question in this and other contexts that dismissing the concept out of hand as impossible--and claiming that nothing can be read that way when the asker did do that--seems unfair to the asker. Really, I don't like having to say, for example, *pick 2 different things* instead of  *pick 2 things* anymore than you do, but that *different* isn't, like, *expensive*, and its presence means no one asks questions like this anymore.

Comment: It's true that it's not necessarily expensive, but it's also not necessary because the words used have a clear meaning, and hence the game doesn't need/bother to specify that “one creature/level” means “one creature/level, each creature being different”. It's a bit of a disservice to reinforce misunderstandings of normal words by treating them as anything more than misunderstandings. (And actually, it *does* make that much more expensive to write.)

Comment: I just can't agree that a lone sentence in the rulebook saying *Unless stated otherwsie, when you can pick multiple things, one thing can't be picked more than once* will somehow bankrupt Paizo. I think you're vastly underestimating how often this issue arises. Despite our best efforts, folks are *making* English work this way (or, at least, trying), so saying English *doesn't* work that way isn't going to hold sway for much longer.

Comment: That line wouldn't be correct for a number of effects—multiple rays, for example. A correct clarification (when the words already say precisely the same thing) would be harder than that, and (as programmers know), every fix is a chance to introduce even weirder bugs. It's not broken and needs no fix. People misreading it… well, people misread everything, forever. Even lawyer-like precision doesn't prevent people misreading actual laws/contracts. That's why there are experts to correct people, and rulebook perfection for every reader ever isn't possible, nor a worthwhile unicorn to chase.

Comment: Wait a second! My misspelled clarification in a comment on a Q&A board is insufficient to alter the next printing of the core rulebook of one of the industry's most popular products?! I'm shocked! *Shocked!* `:-)` (Though it does actually work for like *magic missile* and *scorching ray* as they say otherwsie [sic].) I'm sorry that the phrase we're discussing *can* be read differently (and it can because folks do), but just saying that the phrase shouldn't be read differently then saying that the rules are *already* clear does *not* make the rules any clearer.

Answer (score 13):

It's not a ray. The targeting line isn't touch.

It works by asking you to select the number creatures you want to affect (with a limit on distance from you and each other). You can choose up to one/(your level). That many creatures get exactly the effect, and no more. No creature can be “selected twice” — selecting a creature just includes or excludes it from the effect. There's no “hitting” one creature multiple times — only choosing or not choosing it to be affected at all by the spell.

Comment: I was pretty sure that you wouldnt be able to affect the same creature multiple times but it was worth asking just to turn them from meh healing into great healing.

Comment: Well, after all it is cure *light* wounds.

Comment: I feel like Heal is the only real healing spell once your able to cast it as it out performs any of the other healing spells I know.

Comment: That's levels for you.

Comment: @Fering You're not wrong. Once *heal* does come online at level 11 it **is** the only fixin'-da-hp spell that matters unless really weird circumstances dictate otherwise (*mass cure light wounds* to heal a group of low-level soldiers, for instance).

Comment: I've made great use of Cure Serious and Cure Critical in cases where an ally had been hit but not for enough to justify a Heal slot, but could be in danger before my next turn. Heal is obviously the *best* spell at healing, but not always the most appropriate. (the 2c of a full campaign spent on a monk-cleric)

Answer (score -1):

No.

From [cure light wounds](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cure-light-wounds/):

> Target: one creature/level, no two of which can be more than 30 ft. apart

You target one creature/level.  You have a spell that affects multiple creatures and get to choose which creatures to target.  If you are level 3 and choose the same creature 3 times, how many creatures are you affecting?   You're still only affecting one creature.  If you could choose the same creature more than once then you could choose the same creature however many times you wanted because it is still 'one creature' affected by the spell, leading to a contradiction.

> DESCRIPTION: You channel positive energy to cure 1d8 points of damage + 1 point per caster level (maximum +25) on each selected creature

So you *select* creatures.  When choosing teammates for some sport you don't get to choose the same person twice.  Selection is a yes or no operation, either they are selected or not.

Comment: Im curious why you tried to answer the question with no new information or even a differing view point from already upvoted, accepted, and much older answers.

Comment: @Fering I didn't think those were simple enough or easy to understand.  I also didn't see one mentioning the contradiction that would occur if you attempted to select the same creature more than once, the fact that the spell text would technically allow you to keep selecting the same creatures over and over because they would only count as 'one creature' for the target.

Answer (score -2):

I feel that the repeated targeting for best benefit is a fair compromise, without too much rules lawyering.  After all, it is cure light wounds.  Although, even if it did work that way, I can just make the mobs more difficult anyway.  GM creation monsters are how you nuke rules lawyers. :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. While this answer does explain how workable this effect is with *mass cure light wounds*, it could be improved by explaining how such a ruling would ripple throughout the game system (e.g. the spell *wail of the banshee*). That's not my downvote—minority opinions are totally legit here. However, supporting those minority opinions and examining their effects is usually necessary for an answer to be upvoted. Anyway, thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: For instance, would it be reasonable to heal a creature for (HDd8+5)*CL, up to 20d8+100 for a 5th level spell slot? What does that implicate for mass Cure Mod/Ser/Crit, etc

Answer (score -4):

I really don't see the problem with allowing multiple, even/uneven targeting, otherwise the spell is practically worthless for a lv 5 spell. GM creation monsters or unusually high CR's beat rules lawyers every time. If a monster wants to utterly destroy a party (i.e. chain lightning which explicitly stated each target can only be targeted once), then something like this as inflict would work just fine.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. A level 10 caster could—with this reading—cast *mass inflict light wounds* to deal one creature 10d8+50 points of damage (average 95) with a Will save (or 10) for half. I mean, sure, divine casters rule, but in the abstract arcane casters are supposed to be better in the blasting department! This change would alter this idea significantly. (Not to mention force one dude to make at least 17 save-or-die rolls against *wail of banshee*!) If this answer could offer a comparison that shows this is fair, I'd upvote it! Thank you, though, for trying to help!