# Is it possible to make Shaman's Life Link stronger?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, healing, shaman

Is it possible to increase the healing from Shaman's Life Link Hex? At higher levels, 5 hitpoints per round are not such a big deal. Also because it can heal one person once per round it is way less viable against multiple attacks directed at a single character.

Comment: [Strongly related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96955/can-life-link-be-used-to-have-multiple-bonds-active-on-one-creature)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes.

I know of two ways to increase the healing provided by Life Link. You may be able to find more abilities that work similarly.

1. [Lesser Celestial Totem](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/celestial-totem-lesser-su/) - Any creature affected by this rage power will receive additional healing equal to your class level whenever Life Link triggers. You can take 3 levels of [Skald](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald/) and choose this as your rage power. This will allow you to give the rage power to anyone who accepts your Inspire Rage.
2. [Hierophant Spirit](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/Medium/#Hierophant) - With a single level dip in the [Medium](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/Medium) class you can receive the benefits of the Hierophant spirit, which will increase your Life Link healing from 5 to 7.

**Note:** With either of these in effect, you would still only lose 5, regardless of how much you heal.

Comment: It would be great if you could also add methods that don't require multiclassing.